# Dash won't launch applications after upgrade to 14.04

Tags: 14.04, unity-dash

I just upgraded to 14.04 from 12.04 LTS and now Dash finds apps, but I can't launch them. It seems to hang - but the system doesn't freeze or crash.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try reinstalling unity with:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install unity
```

Comment: Thank you. Your suggestion worked (though I did have to reboot for it to do so). Now on to the next problem I'm having with the upgrade. Again, thanks.

Comment: In fact, my whole system seems to be working faster now!!

Comment: I'm glad to hear that!